# PHPExcel can't download the file

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I wrote a PHPExcel function. With `$objWriter->save('plan.xls');` it works perfectly on the server. The problem is that I need to download the file in the browser. So I have to take `$objWriter->save("php://output");`. The result is that I get a lot of the following weird characters in the browser:

`��ࡱ�;�� ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������`

Have someone an idea why I get this result and not the correct file as download?

My code at the moment: (At the moment it is a empty file for testing).

```
function loadTableToExcel(){        

    $excel = new PHPExcel();

    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel5');

    ob_end_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="filename.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');     

    $objWriter->save("php://output");
    //$objWriter->save('plan.xls');

    $excel->disconnectWorksheets();
    unset($excel); 
}
```

Comment: Make a minimal test case that displays this behaviour and then show the complete code. You've got a function here, it isn't being called though.